Im trying to traverse through this json data but im not able to get the full path
jsonData = {
    '01042014': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'Apr1', 'children': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'Apr2', 'children': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'Apr3', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'inapr3.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test1.txt'}]}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'inapr2.txt'}]}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'inapr1.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test2.txt'}]}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'inroot.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test1.txt'}],
    'container0': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'dir0', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'test0.txt'}]}],
    'container1': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'dir1', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'test1.txt'}]}],
    'container2': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'dir2', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'test2.txt'}]}],
    'test1': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'testdir0', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'test1.txt'}]}],
    'test2': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'testdir', 'children': []}],
    'testcontainer': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'testdir', 'children': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'Test10', 'children': []}, {'type': 'directory', 'name': 'testdir2', 'children': [{'type': 'directory', 'name': 'test3', 'children': [{'type': 'file', 'name': 'test3file.txt'}]}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test2file.txt'}]}, {'type': 'file', 'name': '2ndcopy.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test0.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test1.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test2.txt'}, {'type': 'file', 'name': 'test3.txt'}]}]
};

def find_file_path(data, filename, container='', path=''):
    for item in data:
        print("Container:", container)
        print("Path:", path)
        print("Item:", item)

        if item['type'] == 'file' and item['name'] == filename:
            return {'container': container, 'filename': filename, 'path': path + '/' + filename}

        if item['type'] == 'directory':
            if item['name'] == filename:
                return {'container': container, 'filename': filename, 'path': path + '/' + filename}
            result = find_file_path(item.get('children', []), filename, container, path + '/' + item['name'])
            if result:
                return result

    return None


# Example usage:
filename = 'test3.txt'
container_data = jsonData['testcontainer'][0]['children']
path = find_file_path(container_data, filename)
if path:
    full_path = '/testcontainer' + path['path']
    print(full_path[1:])  # Removing the leading '/' from the path
else:
    print("File not found.")

In this code I have passed the container and the filename i need .... (i want it to work for all though)
im unable to get the desired output becoz its not traversing through all the directories please help me solve this.
the output is :
testcontainer/test3.txt
the desired output should be
testcontainer/testdir/test3.txt

I think your file searching start at a wrong dir? Try this:
container_data = jsonData['testcontainer']


Yes you are right... after pushing container directly without searching for children i was able to traverse
